# Who are the actors of the video game “Chess Wars: A Medieval Fantasy?”

Tags: video-games, behind-the-scenes, actors

For those of you who don’t know, “Chess Wars: A Medieval Fantasy” is a 1996 computer chess game similar to “Battle Chess.” One big difference is that “Chess Wars” has full-motion video sequences that play whenever a piece captures a piece.

According to [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165146/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm), Black Knight is played by Andrew Calder and White Knight is played by Kirk B.R. Woller. Unfortunately, that is all that IMDB lists for the cast.

However, one person who goes by the handle “JMan31337” set up [a playlist of the cutscenes](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqKtQn1_GfviETzNSIGRgAbBn_5TFUJ2o) on YouTube. This should help in trying to identify the actors.

Does anyone recognize the actors?

Comment: This copy of 3do magazine states there were 18 main cast, 6 stuntmen and over 100 extras!! https://archive.org/details/3-do-02

Comment: Well, I found that line on page 16. Wow, 3DO. I had forgotten that console. Then again, it cost $699, and a lot of the games for it were interactive movies. Still, if there were that many people involved, then IMDB should have way more than just two people, shouldn't it?